# Stuck while trying to show fundamental solution $\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|x|$ satisfies $\Delta \phi(x) = \delta(x)$ in 2d?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I am trying to show that the fundamental solution to the Laplacian in 2D satisfies

$$\Delta \phi(x) = \delta(x)$$

where $x = (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

So the fundamental solution in 2D is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|x|$ and we have

$$\Delta \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|x| = \delta(x)$$

$$\int_B \Delta \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|x| dx = \int_B\delta(x)dx$$

where $B$ is the unit ball.

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_B \Delta \ln|x| dx = 1$$

$$\int_B \Delta \ln|x| dx = 2\pi$$

Using the divergence theorem we transform this to a surface integral

$$\int_{\partial B} \frac{\partial \ln|x|}{\partial \nu(x)}  dx = 2\pi$$

where $\nu$ is the normal derivative. I can't see where to go from here?

Comment: And $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Hajo Yes that is the case.